# SQLAlchemy: Execute/Add a function to a column in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy and I have a query from which one of the columns I obtain is a constant QUOTE_STATUS_ERROR, the values in this column are integers. Since the constant value doesn't mean anything to the end-user, I'd like to convert that value from within the query itself to show a string by mapping the values of that column to a dictionary that I have in the app using a function I have in place for that purpose already. I haven't been able to find a way to implement it since Columns in the query are object not value of the column itself.  To make my question clear this is an example of what I have:

Query:

```
q = meta.session.query(MyModel.id, MyModel.quote_status).join(AnotherModel).subquery("q")
```

Function I want to use:

```
def get_status_names(status_value):
    return QUOTE_STATUS_NAMES[status_value]
```

Is there a way to this directly from SQLAlchemy by attaching/passing a function (get_status_names()) to the column (MyModel.quote_status). If not what could be the best approach? I prefer not iterate over the values once I get the results in case the list of results is extensive. I would appreciate a push in the right direction.

**UPDATE:** I'm joining the resulting subquery with other tables

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do.

Off the top of my head...

1. If you just want to display things, you can use a property decorator:

---

```
QUOTE_STATUS__ID_2_NAME = {}

class MyModel(object):
    id = Column()
    quote_status_id = Column()

    @property
    def quote_status_string(self):
        if self.quote_status_id:  
            return QUOTE_STATUS__ID_2_NAME[self.quote_status_id] 
        return None
```

---

1. If you want to render/accept strings and have sqlalchemy convert from string/int transparently, you can use a TypeDecorator -- http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#custom-types

Personally, I usually go for the property decorator.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan quick question. I'm using a subquery (updated post accordingly). Tried the approach you suggested but it doesn't work. While calling it directly it requires that I do with an instance of the Model I'm calling the property on.

Comment: Ah.  The `@property` will only work on the object ( if you do `query(MyModel)` or have a query that creates a MyModel orm instance ).  Your query of `query(MyModel.id, MyModel.quote_status)` only returns those columns -- you'll have to use a custom TypeDecorator and/or custom Column to handle that.

Comment: Here's an example -- http://pieceofpy.com/2011/10/12/sqlalchemy-custom-types-integers-datetime/